# Check if two strings contain the same pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have the following list:

```
names = ['s06_215','s06_235b','s06_235','s08_014','18:s08_014','s08_056','s08_169']
```

`s06_235b` and `s06_235`, `s08_014` and `18:s08_014` are duplicated. However, as shown in the example, there is no specific pattern in the naming. I need to do a pairwise comparison of the element of the list:

```
for i in range(0, len(names)-1):
    for index, value in enumerate(names):
        print names[i], names[index]
```

I need then to check for each pair, if the two, contain the same string but with length more than `4`. That is `s06_235b` and `s06_235`, and `s08_014` and `18:s08_014` would pass this criterion but `s08_056` and `s08_169` would not.

How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: maybe just parse it by regular expression, so it's all in the same pattern something like `s\d\d_\d{2,3}`? Afterwards you just take uniq elements from your list

Comment: You wrote your example strings wrong: `s08_214` and `18:s08_014` are not containing each other.

Comment: sorry, corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an 'in' operator to see if on variable contains another

```
if "example" in "this is an example":
```

Try this:

```
for i in range(0, len(names)-1):
    for index, value in enumerate(names):
       if names[i] in names[index] and len(names[i]) > 4:
          print names[i], names[index]
```

Edit:
As tobias_k mention: Note that this only works if the entire string is contained in the other string

Comment: Note that this only works if the _entire_ string is contained in the other string, not if they share some common substring. Also, why are you mixing `range` and `enumerate` like this?

Comment: @tobias_k. Thanks, I'll edit the answear. I just inserted the if-statement in OPs code to show where it goes.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate all the [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), `join` them with some special character that can not be part of those strings, and use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) like `(\w{5,}).*#.*\1` to find a repeated group in that pair. Other than just testing with `s1 in s2`, this will also work if just a part of the first string is contained in the second, or vice versa.

Here, `(\w{5,})` is the shared substring of at least 5 characters (from the `\w` class in this case, but feel free to adapt), followed by more characters `.*` the separator (`#` in this case), more filler `.*` and then another instance of the first group `\1`.

```
p = re.compile(r"(\w{5,}).*#.*\1")
for pair in itertools.combinations(names, 2):
    m = p.search("#".join(pair))
    if m:
        print("%r shares %r" % (pair, m.group(1)))
```

Output:

```
('s06_215', 's06_235b') shares 's06_2'
('s06_215', 's06_235') shares 's06_2'
('s06_235b', 's06_235') shares 's06_235'
('s08_014', '18:s08_014') shares 's08_014'
('s08_014', 's08_056') shares 's08_0'
('18:s08_014', 's08_056') shares 's08_0'
```

Of course, you can tweak the regex to fit your needs. E.g., if you do not want the repeated region to be bounded by `_`, you could use a regex like `p = r"([a-z0-9]\w{3,}[a-z0-9]).*#.*\1"`.